# How to write a JSONata query to get sum of values related to another distinct attribute?

Tags: json, parsing, jsonata

I have been having trouble finding an appropriate solution for this as I have little experience working with JSON arrays and querying json with JSONata

**Here is a simplified version of my JSON array:**

```
[
  {
    "job":1,
    "issue":"red",
    "issuesInJob":50
  },
  {
    "job":1,
    "issue":"blue",
    "issuesInJob":50
  },
  {
    "job":2,
    "issue":"orange",
    "issuesInJob":20
  },
  {
    "job":2,
    "issue":"orange",
    "issuesInJob":20
  },
  {
    "job":3,
    "issue":"green",
    "issuesInJob":20
  },
    ..........
]
```

## Explaining the array

There are different `"job"`s which have an assigned number. Each object in the array is meant to show a type of `"issue"` that happened in the job, example: `"green"` or `"red"` or `"orange"`. Each job can have multiple issues, even multiple issues of the same type.

`"issuesInJob"` is the total number of issues in the job, meaning that if the value is 50 for job 1, then there are 50 objects in the array with the pair `"job":1`

## Desired output

I would like to get the sum of the total number of `issuesInJob` for all the jobs, knowing that for each job, `issuesInJob` must be counted only once (one distinct value for `issuesInJob` for each job), and that two distinct job may have the same number of issues.

For example, the sum in the part of the array that I provided would be: **50 + 20 + 20 = 90**

I initially summed up every distinct `issuesInJob`, but since two different jobs can have the same number of issues, it wouldn't work.

One thing to note is I can't change the structure of the array, which would've been simpler to get the desired results easier, I have to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$reduce function](https://docs.jsonata.org/higher-order-functions#reduce) to get only the first entry for each job and remember the already-seen jobs in the accumulator:

```
$reduce(data, function ($acc, $item) {
  $item.job in $acc.seenJobs
    ? $acc
    : {
        "seenJobs": $append($acc.seenJobs, [$item.job]),
        "total": $acc.total + $item.issuesInJob 
      }
}, { "seenJobs": [], "total": 0 }).total
```

See it on the Playground: https://stedi.link/ZzWncEc

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using a JSONata expression that groups the data by the 'job' attribute and then sums up the distinct 'issuesInJob' values for each job. Here's the JSONata expression to accomplish this:

```
$sum($map($distinct(data.job), function($v, $i, $a) { $lookup($filter(data, function($v2, $i2, $a2) { $v2.job = $v }), 'issuesInJob')[0] }))
```

You can break down the expression as follows:

- $distinct(data.job): Get distinct job values.
- $map(...): Map over the distinct job values.
- $filter(...): Filter the original data array to get items with the current job value.
- $lookup(...): Get the 'issuesInJob' value for the first item in the filtered array.
- $sum(...): Sum up the 'issuesInJob' values for all distinct jobs.

You can check out this expression in Stedi's JSONata Playground: https://stedi.link/ben201H